# Using operator ^ with `double` operands emits compiler error

Tags: c++

I have come up with some code and it does not compile.

Error   1   error C2296: '^' : illegal, left operand has type 'double'
    2   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or enum type

The code I was able to come up with is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void getnumbers();
void showmean();
void showdev();

double x1, x2, x3, mean, dev;

void getnumbers()
{
    cout<<"Please enter three numbers\n";
    cin>>x1,x2,x3;
}

void showmean()
{
    mean=(x1+x2+x3)/3;

    cout<<"The mean of"<<x1<<", "<<x2<<", "<<x3<<" is "<<mean<<endl;
}

void showdev()
{
    dev=sqrt((x1 - mean)^2) + (x2 - mean)^2 + (x3 - mean)^2/3;

    cout<<"The standard deviation of"<<x1<<", "<<x2<<", "<<x3<<" is "<<dev<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    getnumbers();
    showmean();
    showdev();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (i think your cin syntax is wrong but i could be wrong because i don't know what you're asking)

Comment: @Collin the code does't execute. Errors in The Error List on Visual Studio 2010 are listed at the top of the question. Edited now

Comment: I think he's wondering why the bitwise XOR operator in C++ doesn't work as an exponent operator. Sure it will compile. but....

Comment: @WhozCraig er no, the code looks right to me but the square root function is giving me stress

Comment: You've simply posted your code and asked why it doesn't compile. This is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: er no, the square root function is giving you stress for a reason.  Read whozCraig's comment again

Comment: @bames53 I'm very new here. Discovered the site 20 minutes ago. I amended my question to reflect where I thought the problem was - but my bad.

Comment: @WizaJ um.. you intended to xor with 2 ?? `dev=sqrt((x1 - mean)^2) + (x2 - mean)^2 + (x3 - mean)^2/3;`

Comment: If you want to ask this sort of question I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com is probably a better place. (although I don't use it so maybe they won't like this question either)

Comment: @WhozCraig No, sorry. I've understood your first comment now. I was incorrectly using the ^

Comment: @bames53 thanks. If I am unable to get the desired results here I will try there as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can't take powers like that in C++

   - Use `std::pow()` or `x*x` for mathematical x<sup>2</sup>
2. For multiple inputs it's `cin >> x1 >> x2 ...etc`
3. In your SD equation, your close paren is in the wrong spot I think, mathematically.

   - it should be `SD = sqrt( (x*x + y*y) / z )`. Your close paren makes it x + y*y/3 (or y<sup>2/3</sup>, forget precedence)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the incorrect operator for squaring the values, and the missing parenthesis, the given program doesn't fulfill the part of the assignment that says that the functions should *return* the calculated values. For example:

```
double calculate_mean()
{
    return (x1+x2+x3)/3;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good point, this should also be changed in your program and will involve a little rewrite of your entire program unless you just complete the assignment for the sake of completing it.

Comment: Meaning to say that, I should have separate functions for calculating and showing the mean, then?

Comment: @AK4749 I'm willing to rewrite the whole thing from scratch if it means that I can get it right, understand the concepts and get full marks on it.

Comment: It is up to you. The assignment doesn't require either way. In general, it is better to separate calculation from presentation code, as well as make functions when possible that behave like mathematical functions. I.e. pure without side effects.